# jquery Each - how to build method chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to chain methods dynamically for one object using jQuery $.each or something similar

My function looks like this right now. I parse an array of strings and pass to the typewriter.js script

```
  function initTypewriter(){
    if ( $('[js-typewriter]').length > 0 ){
      $('[js-typewriter]').each(function(i,el){
        var typewriter = new Typewriter(el, {
          loop: true
        });
        var strings = $(el).data("type").split(';');

        typewriter
          .typeString(strings[0])
          .pauseFor(2000)
          .deleteAll()
          .typeString(strings[1])
          .pauseFor(2000)
          .deleteAll()
          .typeString(strings[2])
          .pauseFor(2000)
          .start();

      })
    }
  }
```

The problem is then it could be 10 or 20 strings in the array. SO I would love to DRY my code in something like ...

```
    $.each(strings, function(i,str){
      // hot to add to chain of typewriter instance ?? 
      .typeString(str)
      .pauseFor(2000)
      .deleteAll()
    })
```

.. so I shouldn't repeat same 20 times

Comment: Have you tried just using `typewriter.typeString...`?

Comment: how about just using a foreach loop?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what library you're using, but this should work:

```
var chained = typewriter;
$.each(strings, function(i,str){
  chained = chained
  .typeString(str)
  .pauseFor(2000)
  .deleteAll();
});
chained.start();
```

Most functionality that uses chaining returns the instance after each call. Taking advantage of that by setting a variable to the instance after chaining means you always have the instance with the latest chained functions added to it.

You could just use `typewriter` instead of `chained` -- that variable was introduced to make the chaining aspect clearer.

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you :)